# 802.11ac: What is the benefit of MU-MIMO?

Tags: wireless

Say you have a 3x3 AP and three clients.

Without MU-MIMO, **one** client can receive **three** spatial streams per time slot.

With MU-MIMO, **three** clients can each receive **one** spatial stream per time slot.

However, the total link capacity per client is still the same over time. So what's the benefit of MU-MIMO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might answer you question.

> When MU-MIMO becomes available, the antennas should be 
>   more relevant. While a single client with one or two antennas 
>   would not be able to fully utilize eight spatial streams offered 
>   by an 8x8:8 11ac AP, it’s possible for several Wi-Fi clients to 
>   share a larger pool of streams and antennas, so that overall 
>   aggregate throughput improves for the client population. 
>   Early demonstrations of a single-stream 11ac radio, mounted 
>   in smartphone prototypes, have delivered approximately 
>   220Mbps in a fairly challenging environment. The faster the 
>   handset can transmit its loads, the better its battery life, 
>   because faster devices spend less time transmitting and more 
>   time “sleeping.”

Source [WHAT YOU NEED 
TO KNOW ABOUT 
802.11AC](http://www.motorolasolutions.com/web/Business/_Documents/White%20Paper/_Static%20files/80211ac_White_Paper_0712-web.pdf)